# How do I remove this margin in CSS without affecting the rest of the site?

Tags: css

I have a map on my web page at http://fattyres-co-uk.stackstaging.com/routes/lake-district/borrowdale-bash/.

It contains a copyright attribution in the bottom right corner which is a unordered list.

I want to remove the left and bottom margin from it but, if I change the margin for ul in my style sheet, it affects every ul on my site and I don't want that.

How do I remove the margin only for for this attribution text?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the class of parent element whose child is the `ul` element.

```
.ol-uncollapsible ul {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But forgive me for my lack of knowledge here. Where would I put that?

Comment: Looks like you are using WordPress so I would suggest you to keep it through `WordPress Dashboard > Appearance > Custom CSS`.

It will make sure the css is loaded after all the css of map is done loading so that the margin can be override.

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I didn't know I could do that. Unfortunately it doesn't work though. I can see that it's been added when I inspect element but it's still been overridden by:

Comment: #content ul, #content ol {
    margin: 0 0 20px 30px;
}

Comment: in style.css in the main theme

Comment: What you can do is, add `!important` to force override. .ol-uncollapsible ul {
   margin: 0 !important;
}

Comment: Oh that's exactly what I was looking for and it works! Thank you for your time and your help.